# tf.keras.optimizers.Adam with tf.estimator model in Tensorflow 2.0.beta is crashing

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow-estimator

I am using `Tensorflow 2.0.beta` with `Python 3.6.6` on `Mac OS` (nightly: `tf-nightly-2.0-preview` `2.0.0.dev20190721` but I never managed to have it working with compat module in `Tensorflow 2.0`).

I am traying to migrate a `tf.estimator` model from `Tensorflow 1.12` (fully working) to `Tensorflow 2.0`. Here is the code:

```
# estimator model
def baseline_estimator_model(features, labels, mode, params):
    """
    Model function for Estimator
    """
    print('model based on keras layer but return an estimator model')

    # gettings the bulding blocks
    model = keras_building_blocks(params['dim_input'], params['num_classes'])

    dense_inpout = features['dense_input']

    # Logits layer
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        logits = model(dense_inpout, training=True)
    else:
        logits = model(dense_inpout, training=False)


    # Compute predictions
    probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    classes = tf.argmax(input=probabilities, axis=1, )

    # made prediction
    predictions = {
        'classes': classes,
        'probabilities': probabilities,
    }

    # to be tested
    predictions_output = tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput(predictions)

    # Provide an estimator spec for `ModeKeys.PREDICT`
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                                          predictions=predictions,
                                          export_outputs={tf.saved_model.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: predictions_output})

    # Compute loss for both TRAIN and EVAL modes
    # old -> loss = tf.compat.v1.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=labels, logits=logits)
    loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)(labels, logits)

    # Generate necessary evaluation metrics
    # old -> accuracy = tf.compat.v1.metrics.accuracy(labels=tf.argmax(input=labels, axis=1), predictions=classes, name='accuracy')
    accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
    accuracy.update_state(labels, logits)

    eval_metrics = {'accuracy': accuracy}

    tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy.result())

    # Provide an estimator spec for `ModeKeys.EVAL`
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                                          loss=loss,
                                          eval_metric_ops=eval_metrics)

    # Provide an estimator spec for `ModeKeys.TRAIN`
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:

        # old but working -> optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001, beta1=0.9)
        # crashing
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01, beta_1=0.9, epsilon=1e-07)

        # old -> train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, tf.compat.v1.train.get_or_create_global_step())
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss,var_list=model.weights)

        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                                          loss=loss,
                                          train_op=train_op)
```

predictions=predictions, loss=loss, train_op=train_op, export_outputs=predictions_output)

If I keep the compat.v1 module it is working:

```
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001, beta1=0.9)
```

If I try to use something without compat.v1 it is crashing:

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01, beta_1=0.9,epsilon=1e-07)
```

with the following error (I am running the code locally for the moment, not on `GCP`):

```
I0721 17:33:04.812453 4526515648 estimator.py:209] Using config: {'_model_dir': 'results/Models/Mnist/tf_1_12/estimator/v3/ckpt/', '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 10, '_save_checkpoints_steps': 10, '_save_checkpoints_secs': None, '_session_config': allow_soft_placement: true
graph_options {
  rewrite_options {
    meta_optimizer_iterations: ONE
  }
}
, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 3, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_log_step_count_steps': 50, '_train_distribute': None, '_device_fn': None, '_protocol': None, '_eval_distribute': None, '_experimental_distribute': None, '_experimental_max_worker_delay_secs': None, '_service': None, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x1c37b11b70>, '_task_type': 'worker', '_task_id': 0, '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_master': '', '_evaluation_master': '', '_is_chief': True, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 1}
I0721 17:33:04.815697 4526515648 estimator_training.py:186] Not using Distribute Coordinator.
I0721 17:33:04.817899 4526515648 training.py:612] Running training and evaluation locally (non-distributed).
I0721 17:33:04.818665 4526515648 training.py:700] Start train and evaluate loop. The evaluate will happen after every checkpoint. Checkpoint frequency is determined based on RunConfig arguments: save_checkpoints_steps 10 or save_checkpoints_secs None.
I0721 17:33:04.834385 4526515648 model.py:211] input_dataset_fn: TRAIN, train

using keras layer and estimator (recommended way)
exporter <tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.exporter.LatestExporter object at 0x1c37b115f8>

I0721 17:33:05.117963 4526515648 estimator.py:1145] Calling model_fn.

model based on keras layer but return an estimator model

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

~/Desktop/Work/Data_Science/Tutorials_Codes/Python/proj_DL_models_and_pipelines_with_GCP/src/model_mnist_2_0_v1/trainer/model.py in train_and_evaluate(FLAGS, use_keras)
    589                                       exporters=exporter)
    590 
--> 591     tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
    592 
    593 def train_and_evaluate_old(FLAGS, use_keras):

~/anaconda-release/conda-env/env_gcp_dl_2_0_nightly/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py in train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
    471         '(with task id 0).  Given task id {}'.format(config.task_id))
    472 
--> 473   return executor.run()
    474 
    475 

~/anaconda-release/conda-env/env_gcp_dl_2_0_nightly/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py in run(self)
    611         config.task_type != run_config_lib.TaskType.EVALUATOR):
    612       logging.info('Running training and evaluation locally (non-distributed).')
--> 613       return self.run_local()
    614 
    615     # Distributed case.

~/anaconda-release/conda-env/env_gcp_dl_2_0_nightly/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py in run_local(self)
    712         max_steps=self._train_spec.max_steps,
    713         hooks=train_hooks,
--> 714         saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
    715 
    716     eval_result = listener_for_eval.eval_result or _EvalResult(

~/anaconda-release/conda-env/env_gcp_dl_2_0_nightly/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py in train(self, input_fn, hooks, steps, max_steps, saving_listeners)
    365 
    366       saving_listeners = _check_listeners_type(saving_listeners)
--> 367       loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
    368       logging.info('Loss for final step: %s.', loss)
    369       return self

~/anaconda-release/conda-env/env_gcp_dl_2_0_nightly/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py in _train_model(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1156       return self._train_model_distributed(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1157     else:
-> 1158       return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1159 
   1160   def _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners):

~/anaconda-release/conda-env/env_gcp_dl_2_0_nightly/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py in _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1186       worker_hooks.extend(input_hooks)
   1187       estimator_spec = self._call_model_fn(
-> 1188           features, labels, ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
   1189       global_step_tensor = training_util.get_global_step(g)
   1190       return self._train_with_estimator_spec(estimator_spec, worker_hooks,

~/anaconda-release/conda-env/env_gcp_dl_2_0_nightly/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py in _call_model_fn(self, features, labels, mode, config)
   1144 
   1145     logging.info('Calling model_fn.')
-> 1146     model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
   1147     logging.info('Done calling model_fn.')
   1148 

~/Desktop/Work/Data_Science/Tutorials_Codes/Python/proj_DL_models_and_pipelines_with_GCP/src/model_mnist_2_0_v1/trainer/model.py in baseline_estimator_model(features, labels, mode, params)
    442         #train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, tf.compat.v1.train.get_or_create_global_step())
    443         #train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, tf.train.get_or_create_global_step())
--> 444         train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss,var_list=model.weights)
    445 
    446         print('step 8')

~/anaconda-release/conda-env/env_gcp_dl_2_0_nightly/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py in minimize(self, loss, var_list, grad_loss, name)
    315     """
    316     grads_and_vars = self._compute_gradients(
--> 317         loss, var_list=var_list, grad_loss=grad_loss)
    318 
    319     return self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, name=name)

~/anaconda-release/conda-env/env_gcp_dl_2_0_nightly/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py in _compute_gradients(self, loss, var_list, grad_loss)
    349       if not callable(var_list):
    350         tape.watch(var_list)
--> 351       loss_value = loss()
    352     if callable(var_list):
    353       var_list = var_list()

TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable
```

Any idea how to fix that ? The error messages was changing over time since `Tensorflow 2.0 alpha`.

I am also looking for a full working example of tf.estimator working with `Tensorflow 2.0`. I have issue to export the model as well. In the official documentation of `Tensorflow 2.0` they only use in their example `compat.v1` and don't export the model. All the online course on tf.estimator from GCP are using  older version of Tensorflow (1.12 - 1.14).